# What's the thing with single inverted comma in Java?

Tags: java, function, methods, addition

I just started learning Java Programming Language and there's one thing that I don't understand.

So, the following code is for calculating the sum of 2 given numbers and basically, this is my main method:

```
public class Addition{

public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner add = new Scanner ( System.in );

    System.out.println("Enter the first number:"+' ');

    int num1 = add.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the second number:"+' ');

    int num2 = add.nextInt();

    int calculate = num1 + num2;

    System.out.println(num1 + ' ' + "+" + ' ' + num2 + "=" + ' ' + calculate);

    add.close();

}
```

So the `' '` given are for the spaces and the code is simply for calculating the sum of 2 given numbers

For example the the 2 numbers are 15 and 5. So the output should be like this:

```
Enter the first number: 
15
Enter the second number: 
5
15 + 5 = 20
```

But No! the output looks like this:

```
Enter the first number: 
15
Enter the second number: 
5
47 + 5 = 20
```

Where there should've been 15 instead of 47. So I replaced the code with a shorter one like this:

```
System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + "= " + calculate);
```

This fixed my problem and the output shows as I expected but I'm wondering. What's the thing with `' '` ? When I put the code as

```
(num1 + ' ' + "+" + num2 + "=" + ' ' + calculate)
```

then instead of showing the input value of `num1` in the output, the value of `num1` is increased by 32 like I was adding 32 to the `num1` when I put the space with `' '`

Basically, I'm asking what's the thing with `' '`?

Comment: `' '` represents a char, as opposed to `" "` which is a string. a char has a numerical value (ASCII value) which is why `' ' + int` returns an int

Comment: why would you write something like that `num1 + ' ' + "+"` in the first place? Even this `"Enter the first number:"+' '`?  That just make it harder to read

Comment: As I mentioned already, the ' ' is for the space so "Enter the first number:"+' ' would output as "Enter the first number:(space)" but that can be shortened with "Enter the first number: " and I'm a beginner so :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `' '` is a character, `" "` is a `String`.

Adding `int` to `String` is concatenation and will result in a `String`

Adding `int` to `char` is a numeric operation with character code(ASCII) and will result in an `int`.

Comment: So it means that ' ' is a char with space and the value of space is 32.

Comment: @RedEyedRocker, yes